# Python Daemons - Program Structure and Exception Control

Tags: python, daemon

I've been doing amateur coding in Python for a while now and feel quite comfortable with it. Recently though I've been writing my first Daemon and am trying to come to terms with how my programs should flow.

With my past programs, exceptions could be handled by simply aborting the program, perhaps after some minor cleaning up.  The only consideration I had to give to program structure was the effective handling of non-exception input. In effect, "Garbage In, Nothing Out".

In my Daemon, there is an outside loop that effectively never ends and a sleep statement within it to control the interval at which things happen.  Processing of valid input data is easy but I'm struggling to understand the best practice for dealing with exceptions.  Sometimes the exception may occur within several levels of nested functions and each needs to return something to its parent, which must, in turn, return something to its parent until control returns to the outer-most loop.  Each function must be capable of handling any exception condition, not only for itself but also for all its subordinates.

I apologise for the vagueness of my question but I'm wondering if anyone could offer me some general pointers into how these exceptions should be handled. Should I be looking at spawning sub-processes that can be terminated without impact to the parent? A (remote) possibility is that I'm doing things correctly and actually do need all that nested handling. Another very real possibility is that I haven't got a clue what I'm talking about. :)

Steve

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions are designed for the purpose of (potentially) not being caught immediately-- that's how they differ from when a function returns a value that means "error". Each exception can be caught at the level where you want to (and can) do something about it.

At a minimum, you could start by catching all exceptions at the main loop and logging a message. This is simple and ensures that your daemon won't die. At the main loop it's probably too late to fix most problems, so you can catch specific exceptions sooner. E.g. if a file has the wrong format, catch the exception in the routine that opens and tries to use the file, not deep in the parsing code where the problem is discovered; perhaps you can try another format. Basically if there's a place where you could recover from a particular error condition, catch it there and do so.

Comment: Thanks, the part I was failing to grasp was catching exceptions at the level I wanted to. I didn't appreciate that I could raise an exception and catch it at a higher level.  This makes life a lot easier than trying return back through every function level to the outermost loop.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since you're new to SO: Please "accept" my answer if you found that it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be "it depends".

If an exception occurs in some low-level function, it may be appropriate to catch it there if there is enough information available at this level to let the function complete successfully in spite of the exception. E.g. when reading triangles from an `.stl` file, the normal vector of the triangle it both explicitly given and implicitly given by the sequence of the three points that make up the triangle. So if the normal vector is given as (0,0,0), which is a 0-length vector and should trigger an exception in the constructor of a Normal vector class, that can be safely caught in the constructor of a Triangle class, because it can still be calculated by other means.

If there is not enough information available to handle an exception, it should  trickle upwards to a level where it can be handled. E.g. if you are writing a module to read and interpret a file format, it should raise an exception if the file it was given doesn't match the file format. In this case it is probably the top level of the program using that module that should handle the exception and communicate with the user. (Or in case of a daemon, log the error and carry on.)